# Pulling Unique Values from Multiple Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, multiple-columns

So I'm working on automating my budgeting spreadsheets with a little automation. For each expense there is a category and then a description of the expense so for example:

[image: Spreadsheet Rough Draft]

What I want to do is on the far right for the total is tally up everything for each category, but I want to populate that list on the fly, so for the category column I want it to look at all the category columns and list out unique categories, so even though I might have 'Grocery' listed twice during the week, it only shows up once in the Total Section. The price column would then be the total of that category spent that week.

The issue I'm having is pulling unique values from multiple columns. The closest I've found is this:

```
=INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF(($A$2:$C$9<>"")*(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$A$2:$C$9)=0),ROW($2:$9)*100+COLUMN($A:$C),7^8)),"R0C00"),)&""
```

It works great if the columns I'm looking at are all next to each other, but the columns I'm using are split up. I can't seem to get it to work with the columns broken up.

My attempt:

```
=INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF((($B$3:$B$35,$E$3:$E$35)<>"")*(COUNTIF($Q$2:Q2,($B$3:$B$35,$E$3:$E$35))=0),ROW($3:$35)*100+COLUMN($B:$B)+COLUMN($E:$E),7^8)),"R0C00"),)&""
```

All I get is 'Error in Value'

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is an awkward data shape that it difficult to write formulas for. Are you open to re-shaping your data?

Comment: I am, but would like to keep it easily read.

Ultimately too, this formula would also transpose to another sheet, so I'd have five of these weekly trackers, then one main page that pulls the totals from every week and display an overall monthly progress.

Think this might be more easily accomplished in VBA?

Comment: For ease of writing formulas, you should have a single column for each header (Price, Category, Description, Index, Week, DayOfWeek) and store all of the data in a single table. You can then create multiple sheets that read / summarize / format the data however you'd like. This would allow you to use pivot tables as well.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'll give that a shot